# Facebook comment box vanished

Tags: facebook

I have just integrated facebook comment plugin and it was working great. But i don't know... somehow i can't see it from today. It just got vanished. I checked everything and all are ok.

My code for facebook plugin:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://eventconnectbd.com/" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

I saw a related problem where it says - just add 'https:' before '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'

I did the same and suddenly it shows up and then vanished again.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "vanished"? Is the html markup still there but hidden? Are there any javascript errors? Ad block?

Comment: html markup is still there and no js error. It seems everything ok but it just cant show up the box. Also the like button for the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its a facebook issue, take a look at this
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/426569287392966?browse=search_5088102e10f3e4014990991

you are not the only one who experiences this problem today.